# Mount usb drive using a script if it's plugged in

Tags: awk, scripting, mount, usb

So I want to mount a usb device using a script if it's plugged in at boot.
The usb device is not plugged in at every boot but others may be so I need to check if the label is correct and then mount it.
So far I have the following line:

```
lsblk -rnpo label,name | awk '$1=="USB_FOO"{mount $2 /path/to/mount}'
```

but executing it gives me the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=6) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

What would be a working example?

Comment: I figured it out using variables in the script, still I am interested if (and how) this can be solved in a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `/etc/fstab`. Just append the following line into the file:

```
/dev/sdX   /path/to/mount   auto   defaults,nofail   0   0
```

Comment: To be sure it's the correct labeled device, use `LABEL=<label>` instead of `/dev/sdX` in the answer. But if this is a homework question to use a script, you're on your own - nobody would write a script fo that, because it is an inherent feature of linux mount.

Comment: You can also add `user` to the options, so that a regular user can mount a device.

Comment: It's no homework question I already figured out a way.
I only read one config file from the device if it's plugged in and then it should be possible to remove it without causing any "damage". So using fstab and letting it mount it automatically would keep the device mounted even after the config file was read. I could use the script to unmount it but it's easier to have the mount, config file reading and the unmount process in one script.